# Clip an image to another image

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to do this window-parallax view effect for my landing page. I have got till here, but I don't know how to clip the image onto the 2nd image. I'm using bootstrap as well [The windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yeVd.png)

```html
<img class="img-fluid center-img" src="img/windowfilled.png" width="512x" height="512x">
<img class="img-fluid center-img" src="img/window.png" width="512x" height="512x">
```

```css
.center-img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: -250px; /* Half the height */
    margin-left: -250px; /* Half the width */
}
```

window is the foreground, and window-filled is the background. I want the result to be like this (Photoshop example) [Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBUPm.png)

Answer (score 0):

place image inside then use border

```
border: 1px;
  border-top-left-radius:20px;
  border-top-left-radius:20px;
```

Px just for example

Comment: So something like this `<img class="img-fluid center-img" src="img/windowfilled.png" width="512x" height="512x">
<img class="img-fluid center-img window-border" src="img/windowinside.png" width="512x" height="512x"
<img class="img-fluid center-img" src="img/window.png" width="512x" height="512x">`

And

```window-border {
border: 1px;
  border-top-left-radius:20px;
  border-top-left-radius:20px;}```

Comment: Why do you repeat `border-top-left-radius` twice?